# Adding ListView inside a ScrollView Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

#### Scenario

I have a ScrollView inside which there are 3 textview and a listview is there .

#### Actual

My ScrollView  is not working because all content fit in a page, this is because of the listview itself got a scrollbar.

#### Expectation

I want the listview scrolling to be disabled so that my main scroll should work which means i could scroll the 3 textview along with the items in the listview.

Comment: Would putting the 3 TextViews as a header, or first view in the ListView accomplish what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in XML, this will disable inside scroll of your `ListView` and you would have opportunity to scroll your parent `ScrollView`:

```
<ListView
    android:scrollable="false" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
    ....
/>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers. Please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.